# How to center ul element of the navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, navbar

I found this mobile navigation menu template: https://codepen.io/Tyutyesz/pen/KKdEjwr

When I tested it and pasted the menu's code for html editor, there is little space between ul element and menu class="navigation__wrapper" (space marked with red borders):

[image]

Codepen is not showing this space, but if I make html file and watch the same code with browser the space is showing up.

Here the empty space is showing up:

```css
.navigation{
  position:relative;
  height:80px;
  padding:0 15px;
  background-color: #00688B;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navigation__logo a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.navigation__logo p{
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation__links{
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:100vh;
  left:-1000px;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
  background:#00688B;
  color:#ffffff;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.navigation__links li{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-alig:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
}
.navigation__links a{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;  
}

#hamburger{
  visibility:hidden;
}
.navigation__button{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  background:transparent;
  border:1px solid #ffffff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.navigation__button span{
  position:absolute;
  left: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:1px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transform-origin:center;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear, all 0.3s linear;
}
.navigation__button span:nth-of-type(1){
  top: 10px;
}
.navigation__button span:nth-of-type(2){
  top: 15px;
}
.navigation__button span:nth-of-type(3){
  top: 20px;
}


/* Here comes the magic */

#hamburger:checked ~ .navigation__links{
  /* Or it can be "input[type="checkbox"] ~ .navigation__links" */
  left:0;
}

/* Styles for our "close" button */
#hamburger:checked ~ .navigation__button span:nth-of-type(1){
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 15px;
}
#hamburger:checked ~ .navigation__button span:nth-of-type(2){
  opacity:0;
}
#hamburger:checked ~ .navigation__button span:nth-of-type(3){
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
  <div class="navigation__logo">
    <a href="/"> 
        <p>Logo</p>   <!-- Your logo goes here -->
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation__wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger">
    <label for="hamburger" class="navigation__button">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="navigation__links">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried `align-items: center;` and `align="center"` for class="navigation__wrapper", ul and li elements, but the empty space always showing up.

Comment: In addition to adding `padding:0;` to the `.navigation__links` class you should also correct  `text-alig:center;` to `text-align:left;` within the `.navigation__links li` rule otherwise you will have an even larger space to the left of th text

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `.navigation_links` has a padding. I tried to add `padding: 0;` in the CCS for `.navigation_links`, and it seems to work.

```
.navigation__links {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    background: #00688B;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Edit: To add on to my original answer, the padding exists because `ul` elements have a [default](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.php) of `padding-left: 40px;`. Hence, an override to the `.navigation_links` class is required if you wish to remove this padding.

Answer (score 0):

There's a **CSS Reset** involved in Codepen's version:

[image: codepen]

And there's no CSS reset in the browser version:

[image: Browser version]

[This is a popular CSS reset you can use](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score -3):

To center a  (unordered list) element within a navigation menu, you can use CSS styles to set the margin and padding of the  element. Here's a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Centered Navigation Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

In this example, the key CSS properties for centering the  element within the navigation menu are:

text-align: center; on the parent  element: This property centers the inline-level children (like the ).

margin: 0; and padding: 0; on the  element: This removes any default margin and padding that browsers may apply to the  element.

display: inline-block; on the

elements: This makes the list items inline, allowing them to be centered within the .

Adjust the styling according to your specific design requirements and preferences.